# SignalR works in Visual Studio but returns 404 when on deployed IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have an ASP .NET web application using SignalR 3.0 in ASP .NET Core 3.1 with a C# client. When I run the application in Visual Studio, the client can connect to signalR just fine. However, when I deploy the application on IIS and update the client-side URL, I get a 404 error. I have verified that I can hit the endpoint from the browser and I get a "connection id required" message. Has anybody else encountered this?

Client code:

```
HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(hubAddress).WithAutomaticReconnect().Build();

try
{
    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    // this is where the 404 exception occurs.
}
```

Server-side mapping code in startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapControllers();
     endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");
});
```

Comment: Can not reproduce this issue with correct URL. If you can share a reproducible sample, we could help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: @SA3709 what is `hubAddress `?